# System.IndexOutOfRangeException mientras declaro una List<>

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estaba teniendo problemas en el ambiente de producción, con que me mandaba directamente a la vista `Error.cshtml` por el `try{} catch{}`, y cuando se lo saque me apareció el siguiente error:

Si alguien puede ayudar se lo agradeceria mucho

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
> at WebLogistica.Controllers.HomeController.VerRemito(String identi) in C:\Users\USER\source\repos\WebLogis\Logis\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 140

Me dice que el error es en la `linea 140`, la cual lo que tengo es `new List<>`, lo cual Me resulta raro ya que no estoy queriendo borrar o acceder a alguna posicion inexistente de una `List<>` o `Array`.

```
private static List<PedidoViewModel> VerRemito(string identi)
{
    List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedidos = new List<PedidoViewModel>(); //Linea 140
    // Mas código...
}
```

Me resulta raro ya que esta linea se repite en otro método privado y no me tira error.
Solo ocurre en el ambiente de **PRODUCCIÓN**.

**Localmente funciona perfectamente**

Método que me tira error en producción:

```
private static List<PedidoViewModel> VerRemito(string identi)
{
    string[] imagenes, rutaSplit, imagenRecuperada, rutaImagen, carpetaDia, carpetaMes, carpetaAnio;
    PedidoViewModel pedido;
    List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedidos = new List<PedidoViewModel>(); //Linea 140

    try
    {              
        // \imagenes\..
        carpetaAnio = Directory.GetDirectories(@"wwwroot\imagenes\");

        foreach (var carAnio in carpetaAnio)
        {
            carpetaMes = Directory.GetDirectories(carAnio);
            foreach (var carMes in carpetaMes)
            {
                carpetaDia = Directory.GetDirectories(carMes);
                foreach (var carDia in carpetaDia)
                {
                    imagenes = Directory.GetFiles(carDia);
                    foreach (var img in imagenes)
                    {
                        rutaSplit = img.Split("\\");
                        rutaImagen = img.Split("wwwroot");
                        imagenRecuperada = rutaSplit[5].Split("_");
                        imagenRecuperada[2] = CleanString(imagenRecuperada[2]);

                        if (identi == imagenRecuperada[2])
                        {
                            pedido = new PedidoViewModel();
                            pedido.setNumeroPedido(imagenRecuperada[0]);
                            pedido.setNumeroEntrega(imagenRecuperada[1]);
                            pedido.setNumeroRemito(identi);
                            pedido.setimagenes(rutaImagen[1]);
                            pedido.setMonto("$11111");
                            listaPedidos.Add(pedido);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return listaPedidos;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Metodo que funciona bien en producción:

```
private List<PedidoViewModel> VerPedido(string identi)
        {
            string[] imagenes, rutaSplit, imagenRecuperada, rutaImagen, carpetaDia, carpetaMes, carpetaAnio;
            PedidoViewModel pedido;
            List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedidos;

            try
            {
                listaPedidos = new List<PedidoViewModel>();

                // \imgAndroid\..   
                carpetaAnio = Directory.GetDirectories(@"wwwroot\imgAndroid\");

                foreach(var carAnio in carpetaAnio)
                {
                    carpetaMes = Directory.GetDirectories(carAnio);
                    foreach (var carMes in carpetaMes)
                    {
                        carpetaDia = Directory.GetDirectories(carMes);
                        foreach (var carDia in carpetaDia)
                        {
                            imagenes = Directory.GetFiles(carDia);
                            foreach (var img in imagenes)
                            {
                                rutaSplit = img.Split("\\");
                                rutaImagen = img.Split("wwwroot");
                                imagenRecuperada = rutaSplit[5].Split("_");

                                if (identi == imagenRecuperada[0])
                                {
                                    pedido = new PedidoViewModel();
                                    pedido.setNumeroPedido(identi);
                                    pedido.setNumeroEntrega(imagenRecuperada[1]);
                                    pedido.setNumeroRemito(imagenRecuperada[2]);
                                    pedido.setimagenes(rutaImagen[1]);
                                    pedido.setMonto("$11111");
                                    listaPedidos.Add(pedido);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return listaPedidos;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Esta es mi ruta cuando ejecuto la aplicación localmente:

```
C:\Users\USER\source\repos\DesarrolloWebLogistica\WebLogistica\wwwroot\imgAndroid\2022\08\09\[Imagenes]
```

Esta es mi ruta en ambiente producción:

```
\\rivadavia\c$\carpetaVirtual\proyecto\wwwroot\imgAndroid\2022\08\09\[Imagenes]
```

Comment: Y si muestras el resto del método? Con lo que has puesto, te diría que tu versión local es diferente a la versión de producción. O, tal vez el constructor de la clase `PedidoViewModel` realiza operaciones con índices que están causando el error.

Comment: A ver dejame agragarlo

Comment: Los metodos son los mismos...Nunca tuve un problema similar, por eso me resultó raro también

Comment: porque programas en c# como si fuera Java????porque tu metodo verremito es static?tu controller es estatico???

Comment: esta linea: imagenRecuperada[2] = CleanString(imagenRecuperada[2]); puede fallar claramente si el split anterior no anduvo.. de paso, probaste seguir tu codigo y ver donde falla????

Comment: Lo seguí en debug y no falla en ningún lado, solamente falla en producción, debuguendo el Split() funciona bien

Comment: porque lo que vos pensas que esta correcto, en produccion no esta correcto!!! tu estructura de carpetas y nombres de archivos en produccion no cumple las reglas que vos pensas. Y vuelvo a preguntar, porque programas en C# como si fuera java??? c# tiene get y set implicitos... no necesitas escribir metodos para ellos...

Comment: Si te soy sincero, así me enseñaron en la universidad...

Comment: Revisa los logs, ¿qué error dice? Por otro lado, lo que te enseñaron en la universidad está para nivel universitario, saliendo de ella, hay que expandirse por nuevos caminos.

Comment: Actualmente no estoy con mucho tiempo para tomar un curso mas avanzado... me falta poco para terminar la uni...despues de eso tomaré cursos e investigaré mas a profundidad. Los logs tiraban un error 404.

Comment: Agrega la información de ese log, y despreocúpate por llevar cursos avanzados ahora mismo, todos tienen prioridades y cada quien avanza al ritmo que quiere y puede. Conozco programadores que son eminencias haciendo "hola mundos" y no pasa nada, también hay mercado para ellos; es un bonito momento para ser desarrollador :D

Comment: Las properties existen en .net desde la version 1.. o sea, nunca se programo asi en .net.. igual, obviando eso, un 404 es otro problema totalmente diferente... vas a tener que generar un log en produccion, o copiar lo que hay en produccion a tu entorno de desarrollo/homologacion para ver que pasa...